# I am supposed to get download speed of 150KB/s but I am getting 10MB/s for some sites. How come?

Tags: windows-7, networking, internet, download, bittorrent

I have a 1 mbps connection which means I should get around 130-150KB/s download speed. Which I do. But in case of youtube I download videos at 1Mb/s or more. In case of torrent, I often get 5-10MB/s speed(I can download 700 MB movie within 2-4 mins). But when I download stuff from any other site, I get regular 130-150KB/s I heard that ISP can remove speed limit or set higer speed limit exception  for specific sites. That is the only explanation I have. How can I make the most out of this? Can I somehow get this speed for downloads from other sites too? 
Note: these are not spikes! I am talking constant 5-10MB/s

Comment: Share your ISP details too. as I also get such speed variations. specifically from speedtest.com

Comment: @AEonAX ISP details such as?

Comment: My completely unfounded hunch is that your ISP may have a YouTube cache server on their network, and for torrents there may be peers on the same ISP. Your ISP may not be limiting in-network traffic, which could allow those sources to load faster than the internet at large.

Comment: I think @AEonAX means who your ISP is, what geographical region you're in, if it's cable or DSL, etc.

Comment: who provides you internet? company name etc. not the local service provider.

Comment: ion D-Vois  , Mumbai, Cable.

Comment: How do I find out what other sites I can go to get this super  fast speed? I get similar highspeed on google playstore.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your ISP, and unfortunately you havn't specified how you connect (Ethernet, ADSL, VDSL, WIFI or something else), but your speed is a combination of factors.

The first limiting factor is the speed of the connection between you and your ISP (ie the last mile).   That is typically (but not always) a hard limit defined by the technology - and I suspect you are not capped here.

The next limit is any rate limiting that the ISP imposes on your connection.  Your ISP has some flexibilty here, for example they can (and often do) allow bursts - usually short ones of high speed as this means websites feel snappier, but overall you are not using more resources.    But here is the thing - these rate limits can be placed on selective paths.  You may well find that the ISP is not rate limiting traffic originating in their network - and as someone else pointed out - if Google has a proxy there it may be bypassing the limit - heck, Google may be paying them for bandwidth, so they may want it to be as fast as possible.   This method of rate limiting is what is probably being applied, and could explain your speeds.

The last limit is a congestion limit, which means too many people trying to use a limited pipe.  Not worth discussing that one here.

Comment: ISP: D-Vois SSV , cable internet.  I dont get spikes I get constant high speed on certain sites which includes download from google playstore , certain microsoft sites too. And of course torrent. It is hard to imagine that all of them are paying them .  Is there a way I can find out on what other sites I can get this high speed? (probably not). Is there a way I can fool ISP regarding the source of download? ( I am a lay man when it comes to networking)

Comment: I-ON does cache most used file downloads. if you have unlimited connection use dc++ on d-vois hub. Mostly used download sites like google/youtube servers, java downloads etc are cached, they also have seeders for popular torrents for hi-speed internal download.

Comment: @AEonAX I used  to use DC++ , not anymore since I noticed speed on bittorrent to be better than DC++. But thanks for suggesting. :)